# How to calculate number of selections of a group of 4 people from a pool of 12 subject to constriants?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Full question: *How to calculate number of selections of a group of 4 people from a pool of 12 people subject to the constraint that the selection of 4 people from the pool of 12 will always contains two specific individuals, A and B*.

**Starting Facts:**
Men = 5
Women = 7
Sample = Men + Women = 12

Tom $\subset$ Men
Sally $\subset$ Women

Given the data above, what are the number of selections that include **both Tom and Sally**?

First, I calculated the total number of combinations of 4 individuals from the pool of 12 individuals:

$$ C_4^{12} = \cfrac{12!}{4!(8!)} = 495 $$

My intuition is that I'll need to implement the combinations formula twice more to calculate the number of selections that include Tom and Sally, but I'm not sure what line of reasoning to follow.

I also know that the correct answer is 45 selections.

Would appreciate either direct answers or hints. Thanks!

Comment: "*What are the number of selections...*"  Selections of what size?  Of any size?  Of a specific size?  You use the number $4$ later on, but the number $4$ didn't appear in the problem statement before this.

Comment: A couple of things: first, the symbol "$\subset$" means a *subset*, whereas Tom is an *element* or a *member* of the set; use "$\in$" for this (`\in`). Second, why are you taking combinations of $4$ individuals?

Comment: Are selections always of size 4? or can the selections be of any size <= 12?

Comment: As for a hint... if we are wanting to get four people... Let us go ahead and put tom and sally into the group.  We still need to chose two more people out of the ten remaining people...  So we have *ten* and we want to *choose two* of them to also include... (*If we are wanting groups of any size... put tom and sally into the group... then from the remaining ten people, choose any subset of them of any size to put into the group as well*)

Comment: @JMoravitz I've edited the title and content of the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we fix Tom and Sally in the group, we need 2 of the other 10 people to fill the group. The number of ways to do this is 
$${10 \choose 2} = 45$$